# Seeking the analytical proof using the method of induction

Tags: induction

Experimentally (using Wolframalpha) I noticed that
for $n=2,3,4,5$

$\log[n^2] - \log[n^2 - 1] = \sum((\frac{1}{n^4})^{k+1}\left(\frac {n^2}{(2k+1)}+\frac {1}{2k+2}\right),k = 0\cdots \infty$

Wolframalpha also confirms the generalization of the above as follows:

for $|n| > 1$

$\log[n^2] - \log[n^2 - 1] = \sum((\frac{1}{n^4})^{k+1}\left(\frac {n^2}{(2k+1)}+\frac {1}{2k+2}\right),k = 0\cdots \infty$

Could someone provide analytical prove for my above described generalization using induction?

Comment: @alex I have attmpted to format your question, can you tell me if I have the details correct?

Comment: @user317176 Yes, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A standard Maclaurin series is
$$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m}\quad\hbox{for $|x|<1$}.$$
If $|n|>1$ then $0<1/n^2<1$ so we can substitute $x=1/n^2$ to get
$$-\log\Bigl(1-\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1m\,\frac{1}{n^{2m}}\ .$$
Now sum the odd and even terms separately (we can do this because it's a convergent series of positive terms): take $m=2k+1$ for the odd terms, $m=2k+2$ for the even terms, both with $k$ from $0$ to $\infty$, giving
$$\eqalign{-\log\Bigl(1-\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\Bigl(\frac1{2k+1}\,\frac1{n^{4k+2}}+\frac1{2k+2}
      \,\frac1{n^{4k+4}}\Bigr)\cr
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{n^{4k+4}}\Bigl(\frac{n^2}{2k+1}+\frac1{2k+2}\Bigr)\ .\cr}$$
Since
$$\log(n^2)-\log(n^2-1)=-\log\Bigl(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\Bigr)=-\log\Bigl(1-\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)\ ,$$
this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, Dear David! Could this identity be further generalized to cover Log((n^n)/(n^n - 1))?

Comment: Haven't looked closely but I don't see why not.  You would have terms like $1/n^{nk}$ with $n$ in the exponent as well as the base, but that should not be a problem.

Comment: Log((n^m)/(n^m - 1)) actually for more generality